# Go to the url of the selection after submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select

I have the following code so depending on the selected option, the visitor is directed to a new page on change. But I want them to be directed to that page after they've clicked on the submit button, not immediately on change. How can I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function go()
{
window.location=document.getElementById("link").value
}
</script>
<form>
<select id="link" onchange="go()" > <option>DEFAULT</option>
  <option value="page1.php">TITLE1</option>
  <option value="page2.php">TITLE2</option>
  <option value="page3.php">TITLE3</option>
</select>

<div class="submit">  <input name="submit" type="image" id="submit" src="images/getaquotebutton.png"  height="93" width="259"/> </div><!--end of submit class-->

</form>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Change to an onsubmit event on the form instead of an onchange on the select.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I had tried that earlier but that didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple:

Remove the onchange from here:

```
<select id="link" onchange="go()" >
```

Instead add:

```
<input onclick="go()" name="submit" type="image" id="submit" src="images/getaquotebutton.png"  height="93" width="259"/>
```

#### Edit:

Just noticed the `type` is set to `image`, well if this doesn't work as intended, try to change the `type` to `button` and add image through css as:

```
<input onclick="go()" name="submit" type="button" id="submit" style="background-image: url('images/getaquotebutton.png'); height:93px; width:259px;" />
```

Comment: Thanks but when I did this, the dropdown menu didn't show on the website. So I've edited like this: <script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
window.location=document.getElementById("link").value
}
</script>
<form>
<input onclick="go()" name="submit" type="image" id="submit" src="images/getaquotebutton.png"  height="93" width="259"/>      <option>DEFAULT</option>
      <option value="get-a-storage-quote1.php">TITLE1</option>
      <option value="get-a-storage-quote2.php">TITLE2</option>
      <option value="get-a-storage-quote3.php">TITLE3</option>
</select>
</form>
 Am I missing sth?

Comment: @user3428914 From your code, the `<select id="link">` seems to be missing. Also please note the edit.

Comment: Just to make it easier for others to copy paste, I've made the last class like this since when there is a space between the url and the paranthesis, it doesn't show the background-image.  `<div class="submit"> 
<input onclick="go()" name="submit" type="button" id="submit" style="background-image: url('images/getaquotebutton.png'); height:93px; width:259px;" />
 </div><!--end of submit class-->`

Comment: @Denise That's right, there isn't supposed to be a space, I'll update the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(
    window.location=document.getElementById("link").value;
));
```

Of course you should remove the onchange.

Comment: Thank you though this code gives an error on dreamweaver. might there be any typo here maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    if($('#link').val() == page1.php) { 
        do redirect..
        }
    });
});
```

Do like this for each!